# How to read a property from an ant build file to a gradle build script?

Tags: ant, gradle

I am looking for a possibly clean and concise way of extracting a property from ant's `build.xml` file.

I know I could use `ant.importBuild 'build.xml'` but this would import all the targets, possibly causing name clashes e.g. with the java plugin, which is a [known issue](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-771).

I am using gradle 1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to manually parse the XML file, for example using Groovy's `XmlSlurper` class. However, this won't replace any property references occurring in the property value. Another way is to configure an `org.apache.tools.ant.Project` object (similar to how `ant.importBuild` does it), and get the property value from there. Something like:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.Project
import org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper

task printPropertyValue {
    doLast {
        def antProject = new Project()
        ProjectHelper.configureProject(antProject, file("build.xml"))
        def value = antProject.getProperty("some.property")
        while (value.contains('${')) {
            value = antProject.replaceProperties(value)
        }
        println value

    }
}
```

There may be a better way to recursively replace property references, but I couldn't find one.

Another potential solution is to use an external properties file that's read both by Ant and Gradle.